# How to create a tuple prop-type checker?

Tags: validation, reactjs

I'm trying to create a custom "tuple" prop-type for React, however, I've hit a bit of a roadblock.

The API would look like this:

```
import {PropTypes} from 'react';

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    static propTypes = {
        myProp: tuple(PropTypes.number, PropTypes.string),
    };
```

This would ensure that `myProp` is a 2-element array, with the first element being a number, and the second being a string.

Here's how far I got:

```
export function tuple(...arrayOfTypeCheckers) {
    return requirable(function(props, propName, componentName) {
        let value = props[propName];
        if(!Array.isArray(value)) {
            throw new Error(`Expected array for \`${propName}\` in \`${componentName}\``);
        }
        if(value.length !== arrayOfTypeCheckers.length) {
            throw new Error(`\`${propName}\` must have exactly ${arrayOfTypeCheckers.length} elements in \`${componentName}\`, got ${value.length}`);
        }
        for(let i = 0; i < value.length; ++i) {
            let checker = arrayOfTypeCheckers[i];

            if(!__NEED_HELP_HERE__) {
                throw new Error(`${propName}[${i}] is not of the expected type in \`${componentName}\``)
            }
        }

        return null;
    });
}
```

(Implementation of `requirable` can be found [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1715#issuecomment-168943070))

However, I can't figure out how to implement `__NEED_HELP_HERE__`. `PropTypes.string` is another prop-type with the signature,

```
function(props, propName, componentName)
```

You'll notice it takes an object full of props, plus a propName. The value is accessed as,

```
var propValue = props[propName];
```

Which means I can't supply my own value from the array.

How can I call into React's `PropTypes.xyz` validators?

Answer (score 3):

I found this question useful, so I thought I would provide an updated answer for anyone is looking for this (even if it's a couple years old). The answer is based on the answer by @mpen. It is updated to work with the latest `prop-types` which is version `15.6.2`.

The main updates are the passing of the `secret` (hidden 6th argument to type checker) to the internal type checkers. This allows the use of the standard `prop-types` type checkers with this checker, without them throwing `Error`s. It can also be used within other type checkers (`shape`, `arrayOf`, `objectOf`, `tuple` itself, etc.)

The implementation is also based off the internal implementation of `prop-types` and conforms to their API (returning either an `Error` or `null`).

The implementation of `createChainableTypeChecker` is taken from the library with a few things stripped out (checking the `secret` is right) and added passing the `secret` down.

Here's the solution. It uses ES6 classes and module import/export:

```
function CustomPropTypeError (message) {
  this.message = message;
  this.stack = '';
}
CustomPropTypeError.prototype = Error.prototype;

function createChainableTypeChecker (validate) {
  function checkType (isRequired, props, propName, componentName, location, propFullName, secret) {
    componentName = componentName || ANONYMOUS;
    propFullName = propFullName || propName;

    if (props[propName] == null) {
      if (isRequired) {
        if (props[propName] === null) {
          return new CustomPropTypeError('The ' + location + ' `' + propFullName + '` is marked as required ' + ('in `' + componentName + '`, but its value is `null`.'));
        }
        return new CustomPropTypeError('The ' + location + ' `' + propFullName + '` is marked as required in ' + ('`' + componentName + '`, but its value is `undefined`.'));
      }
      return null;
    } else {
      return validate(props, propName, componentName, location, propFullName, secret);
    }
  }

  var chainedCheckType = checkType.bind(null, false);
  chainedCheckType.isRequired = checkType.bind(null, true);

  return chainedCheckType;
}

export function tuple (...types) {
  return createChainableTypeChecker((props, propName, componentName, location, propFullName, secret) => {
    const value = props[propName];
    if (!location) {
      location = 'prop';
    }
    if (!propFullName) {
      propFullName = propName;
    }

    if (!Array.isArray(value)) {
      return new CustomPropTypeError(`Invalid ${location} \`${propFullName}\` supplied to \`${componentName}\`, expected ${types.length}-element array`);
    }
    if (value.length !== types.length) {
      return new CustomPropTypeError(`Invalid ${location} \`${propFullName}\` supplied to \`${componentName}\`, expected ${types.length}-element array, got array of length ${value.length}`);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < value.length; ++i) {
      const error = types[i](value, i, componentName, 'element', `${propFullName}[${i}]`, secret);
      if (error) {
        return error;
      }
    }

    return null;
  });
}
```

Usage:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import * as CustomPropTypes from './path/to/CustomPropTypes';

class Component extends React.Component { ... }
Component.propTypes = {
  myTupleType: CustomPropTypes.tuple(
    PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    PropTypes.string.isRequired
  ).isRequired,
};

<Component myTupleType={[5, 'string']} />  // No error
<Component myTupleType={['5', 6]} />       // PropType error
```

Caveats:

- `prop-types` discourages creating custom type checkers which use included type checkers (for some reason). This appears to work in `15.6.2`, but I can't guarantee it works in others, or will continue to in the future versions.
- The testing I've done is limited (but has worked without error for me). It's possible edge cases will cause an error (other attempts by `prop-types` to prevent extension).

Answer (score 0):

It's too hard to tap into React's internal API, and they're telling us [not to](https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/dont-call-proptypes.html) anyway, so I had to re-implement the type-checker myself.

Here's the code:

```
const lo = require('lodash');

function tuple(...types) {
    return requirable(function(props, propName, componentName, location, propFullName) {
        let value = props[propName];
        if(!location) {
            location = 'prop';
        }
        if(!propFullName) {
            propFullName = propName;
        }

        if(!Array.isArray(value)) {
            throw new Error(`Invalid ${location} \`${propFullName}\` supplied to \`${componentName}\`, expected ${types.length}-element array`);
        }
        if(value.length !== types.length) {
            throw new Error(`Invalid ${location} \`${propFullName}\` supplied to \`${componentName}\`, expected ${types.length}-element array, got array of length ${value.length}`);
        }
        for(let i = 0; i < value.length; ++i) {
            if(!types[i](value[i])) {
                throw new Error(`Invalid ${location} ${propFullName}[${i}] supplied to \`${componentName}\`, unexpected type`)
            }
        }

        return null;
    });
}

function requirable(predicate) {
    const propType = (props, propName, ...rest) => {
        // don't do any validation if empty
        if(props[propName] === undefined) {
            return;
        }

        return predicate(props, propName, ...rest);
    };

    propType.isRequired = (props, propName, componentName, ...rest) => {
        // warn if empty
        if(props[propName] === undefined) {
            return new Error(`Required prop \`${propName}\` was not specified in \`${componentName}\`.`);
        }

        return predicate(props, propName, componentName, ...rest);
    };

    return propType;
}

const TypeCheckers = {
    TypedArray: lo.isTypedArray,
    Object: lo.isObject,
    PlainObject: lo.isPlainObject,
    RegExp: lo.isRegExp,
    String: lo.isString,
    Undefined: lo.isUndefined,
    Number: lo.isNumber,
    Null: lo.isNull,
    NativeFunction: lo.isNative,
    Function: lo.isFunction,
    Error: lo.isError,
    FiniteNumber: lo.isFinite,
    NaN: lo.isNaN,
    DomElement: lo.isElement,
    Date: lo.isDate,
    Array: lo.isArray,
    Boolean: lo.isBoolean,
    Stringable: obj => obj && lo.isFunction(obj.toString),
};
```

The "types" aren't actual types, they're just functions that take a value and return true or false. I'm using some helper functions from `lodash` because that was a lot easier than trying to rip them out of React, but you can use whatever.

I *am* still utilising the internal API to get the `propFullName` but I put in a fallback in case they remove that. The error messages look really terrible without the full prop name. e.g.

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop 0[1] supplied to `PhsaDocToolbar`, unexpected type

But with `propFullName` we get:

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop docTypes[0][1] supplied to `PhsaDocToolbar`, unexpected type

This only matters of you're creating things like `PropTypes.arrayOf(tuple(TypeCheckers.Number, TypeCheckers.String))`.

Comment: Have you published this code as a project that can be pulled in via `npm`?

Comment: @codermonkeyfuel No, sorry. These functions need a bit more polish before I'd publish them, and I'd probably remove the dependency on lodash.

Answer (score 0):

Did this, and worked fine for me.

```
//Component
<Component state={[10, () => 20]} />

//Tupple
const tupple = (...validators) =>
    PropTypes.arrayOf((_, index) => {
        const currentValidators = validators.filter((v, i) => i === index);
        if (currentValidators.length <= 0) return true;
        const [currentValidator] = currentValidators;

        return currentValidator;
    });

//PropsValidation
SomeComponent.propTypes = {
    state: tupple(
        PropTypes.number,
        PropTypes.func
    ),
};
```