# How to check a specific prop-type against a specific value?

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

Calling prop-types directly has been [deprecated](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/blob/master/README.md#difference-from-reactproptypes-dont-call-validator-functions). They now recommend you check a component's props like this:

```
PropTypes.checkPropTypes(MyComponent.propTypes, props, 'prop', 'MyComponent');
```

But I need to check a specific value against a specific prop-type.

e.g. I have [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39497429/65387):

```
export function tuple(...types) {
    return requirable(function(props, propName, componentName, location, propFullName) {
        let value = props[propName];
        if(!location) {
            location = 'prop';
        }
        if(!propFullName) {
            propFullName = propName;
        }

        if(!Array.isArray(value)) {
            throw new Error(`Invalid ${location} \`${propFullName}\` supplied to \`${componentName}\`, expected ${types.length}-element array`);
        }
        if(value.length !== types.length) {
            throw new Error(`Invalid ${location} \`${propFullName}\` supplied to \`${componentName}\`, expected ${types.length}-element array, got array of length ${value.length}`);
        }
        for(let i = 0; i < value.length; ++i) {
            if(!types[i](value[i])) {
                throw new Error(`Invalid ${location} ${propFullName}[${i}] supplied to \`${componentName}\`, unexpected type`);
            }
        }

        return null;
    });
}
```

And in there it does

```
if(!types[i](value[i])) {
```

Where `types[i]` might be something like `PropTypes.string`. So I want to check if the first array element is a string, and the second array element is a number.

i.e., I don't have an object full of prop-types, nor a props object in this context. I have *one* prop-type and *one* value I want to check.

How can I do that? Does the API not support this use-case anymore?

Comment: You should still be able to use `PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({...})).isRequired` and then `checkPropTypes` should validate against that

Comment: @Purgatory How do you mean? `PropTypes.checkPropTypes(PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({...})).isRequired, [{some: 'value'}])` doesn't match the function signature as they describe it. Secondly, `arrayOf` isn't the same as a tuple. A tuple has an exact length, and each element can be a different type.

Comment: No that is not what i meant, i agree the first argument of `checkPropTypes` needs to be an object of `propTypes` for the props being passed to your component so you would have passed `PropTypes.checkPropTypes({types: PropTypes.arrayOf(...).isRequired}, ...));`.